# Universal search in a selection of records in whatever language they are written for example "A1"

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have an interesting question, I did not find the answer on the internet. I use the apex oracle. It has the function of select list. There I use the query:

```
select c.SEAL_NUMBER r,
       c.SEAL_NUMBER d 
from SEC_SEALS c
where not exists (select null 
                  from SEC_OBJECT_SEALING r
                  where r.SEAL_NUMBER = c.SEAL_NUMBER
                 ) 

       order by  LENGTH(c.SEAL_NUMBER);
```

And I get the answer: A1, A2, A3, A4, A5 .....
When I type in the English language in the function select list A1, it finds it from the list. But is it possible that I could write in the Ukrainian language "A1" and it would find me A1 but it is written with English characters. In essence, the symbols are the same. Thanks for the help)

Comment: I don't understand the question. Could you please clarify. Just in case, maybe this will help? https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/nlspg/linguistic-sorting-and-matching.html#GUID-B0971B89-63EF-409B-B14A-459B8211E764